# Logging instance data

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I was thinking which fields I should include in exception from `ActionExecutingContext` instance and I thought wouldn't it be great to have a helper, that would produce readable text representation of instance data?

I know, that I won't be perfect in all cases - I mean it may go too deep, it may not output everything is needed by default, but it would be better in many cases than just exception message without any data.

Has anyone written such thing, saw in any open source project?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get the values of all properties of an object using reflection:

```
public static void LogPublicProperties(object obj)
{
    foreach (var propertyInfo in d.GetType().GetProperties())
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}",
            propertyInfo.Name,
            propertyInfo.GetValue(d, null));
}
```

If you want to log fields, then use `Type.GetFields()` instead of `GetProperties()`.

Comment: It will get values only from first level properties, and for example in ActionExecutingContext user agent is quite deep inside: filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.UserAgent

Comment: So do this recursively, it's only a matter of how to detect complex properties.

Comment: @Baboon: I guess the problem is, that you don't want to recurse into every property as this would result in a lot of (unneeded) information in the logs.

Comment: So create an attribute to put on types that shouldn't be displayed any further and don't recurse over properties of that type. There is no built-in functionality that says "recurse until it doesn't make sense anymore" ;)

Comment: You can't put attributes on types which are part of the .net framework. You would have to create some external config-/rules-file.