# On exception - convert object to string?

Tags: c#, vb.net, serialization

I've tried to gather as much info as possible, when my VB.Net app crashes.

I have some objects that I need to convert to string, so I can send the objects value to me in an email.

How can I convert an object to string - even if they are not serializable?

In my test, if I try to serialize my test object, I get an error, since it inherits from IDictionary, it can't be serialized. But I can add it to the "Watch" window and still see all its properties. So there must be a way to convert an non serializable object to a string?

Comment: So, are you basically asking for a way to serialize an object? Why don't you try to serialize it to Json, for example. I'm sure it can deal with IDictionary types. Give it a try: http://json.codeplex.com/

Comment: Depending on what you understand by "app crash" - here may be info how to log Exceptions that cause the App to crash (unhandled Exceptions) - (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895929/nlog-configured-to-automatically-log-all-exceptions/13896150#13896150) and just log The Exception with a Logging Framework (which can be configured to send errors via mail, log them to Filesystem...)

Comment: @dandel put it as an answer and I will mark it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had such question before - [Logging instance data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578301/logging-instance-data)

So you can use reflection and go through properties by your own or you can take something, that is already written, for example ServiceStack has Dump method:
http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=202

BTW, not sure what you mean by "not serializable". If object can't be serialized to xml using default .net classes, that doesn't mean it can't be serialized using custom classes or different serialization format, like JSON or binary.

Comment: This looks good, but if I have like this ... Public Function SerializeObject(o As Object) As String ... then o.Dump fails with member Dump is not found in the object. Any how to fix this?

Comment: you need to install package http://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Text/ and add using statment: `using ServiceStack.Text;`

Comment: I did that and if I do MyObject.Dump, it works, but if I send the object as a parameter to my function above ... Call SerializeObject(MyObject) ... then my functions method ... o.Dump ... fails.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using reflection

[Reflection (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: link-only answers are discouraged. You'd better provide some extra explanation or examples.

Answer (score 0):

So, are you basically asking for a way to serialize an object? Why don't you try to serialize it to Json, for example. I'm sure it can deal with IDictionary types. Give it a try: [json.codeplex.com](http://json.codeplex.com)